# PHP Mysql Poll exam inserting?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

table question:

```
id     question
1      myquestion1
2      myquestion2
3      myquestion3
4      myquestion4
5      myquestion5
```

table answer:

```
id qid userid    answer
1  1   1        myanswer
2  2   1        myanswer
3  3   1        myanswer
4  4   1        myanswer
5  5   1        myanswer
```

My problem is how can i insert using php mysql for my answer after answering 5 questions?
any one has an idea?

sample question: After clicking radio button go to next question then after answering submit and insert answer into database..
Are you married?

Yes

No

Do you play basketball?

Yes

No

ect....

Any help very much appreciated! 
Thank you!

Comment: i really hope noone helps you until you accept some answers

Comment: click on your name above, find your previous questions and "accept" the correct answers.

Comment: your profile page http://stackoverflow.com/users/360742/devzone does not have any accepted answers. Go to your questions and accept the best answer by clicking the tick icon on the left side on an answer. This shows gives the answerer a reputation gain and shows others that your question is completed

Answer (score 0):

```
array(
    ['question_id'] =>Yes //Are you married?
    ['question_id'] =>no  //Do you play basketball?
)
```

You need to get this array by posting answer data